# Looking for a better way to sort data

Tags: c++, qt, sorting

I have an algorithm which processes a file across 6 different variable parameters.  The algorithm produces a true/false result for the file on each parameter set.  I run this algorithm across a set of files, getting the resulting true/false's in a vector (as well as some additional, irrelevant data).

Once that algorithm runs, I then want to count the number of true results for each parameter set, as well as the number of files processed.  The way that I do that right now is as follows:

```
while(!results.isEmpty()){ //results being a vector of the individual file results
  for (long i = 0; i < params.size(); i++){ //params being a vector of the parameters
    if (results.first().params... == params[i].params...){
       params[i].numFiles++;
       if (results.first().result){
         params[i].numTrue++;
       }
       results.pop_front();
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

This accomplishes the job, but now that I've optimized my algorithm, this is the last chokepoint in my code, and I am looking for ways to speed this up.  What would be the best way to quckly sort through this data?  If this is relevant, at the moment I am using Qt, and my vectors are currently QVector.

Comment: Is `results` a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? Then simply use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). If it's a Qt container, I'm sure Qt have some sorting functions as well.

Comment: Even with Qt containers, since Qt 5 this is encouraged to use STL over Qt Algos. [Source](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtalgorithms.html)

Comment: quicksort may help you

Comment: results is a QVector.  That being said, how does std::sort help in this situation?

Comment: @user3830784 it might be perhaps that you use the word "sort", indicating that you want to *sort* (order the data in a sorted order) the data. `std::sort` is a standard way to do that. If you *don't* want to re-order the data according to some sorting criteria, then "sort" is not the right term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm has a complexity of O(NxM), where N is the size of result and M is the size of param.

If what you are comparing here:

```
if (results.first().params... == params[i].params...){
```

supports the less operator you can sort params before the first loop. And instead of going through all its elements, just do a binary search. The complexity will be then O(Nxlog(M)).

Answer (score 0):

If there are ready params for comparison

> if (results.first().params... == params[i].params...)

in each result, you can store 6 params in a hash table and search through a hash table each iteration of

> while(!results.isEmpty())

which gives O(N) complexity

but actually real performance depends on hash function. Sometimes O( N log M ) may be better; it depends on operations time.
So it's better to check performance in practice after optimization.

Additional note: current complexity is O(N) anyway because number of params (6 params) is a constant.